# Button action not working after changing initiation eventhandlers from .live to .on in jquery

Tags: jquery

im using now jQuery in version: jquery-1.11.0.min.js

before changing from .live to .on i was using jquery: 1.6.1 (where .live was allowed)

Html for this button:

```
<div class="start"><button>Start</button></div>
```

In _initEventHandlers when i was using 1.6.1 i had a function with this code:

```
$('#ifrform').get(0).setAttribute('action', 'Handler.ashx');
     $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype._initEventHandlers.call(this);
     var filesList = this.element.find('.row.files'), eventData = { fileupload: this };

     filesList.find('.start button')
          .live(
               'click.' + this.options.namespace,
               eventData,
               this._startHandler
          );
```

After change to 1.11.0 i have this code:

```
$('#ifrform').get(0).setAttribute('action', 'Handler.ashx');
     $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype._initEventHandlers.call(this);
     var filesList = this.element.find('.row.files'), eventData = { fileupload: this };

     filesList.find('.start')
          .on(
               'click.' + this.options.namespace,
               'button',
               eventData,
               this._startHandler
          );
```

With .live everything works ok, but with .on there is no action and no errors after button click.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Have you checked the console for errors? I would guess the issue lies elsewhere in your code.

Comment: why is there a dot `.` in your `click.` ? doesnt it be just `click`

Comment: Console returns no errors, im searching problem.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery 1.11 mandates the use of delegate. Both Live and On are deprecated. Check this link [Jquery Delegate](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/). So I would recommend you to shift to that.

A sample usage would be:

```
$( "table" ).delegate( "td", "click", function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "chosen" );
});
```